# why angular stop processing more than one directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why did angular not process the other directive?

I have 2 directives (restrict to Element, restrict: 'E') inside a div.

But angular processed my first directive and did not process the other directive.

```
<div>
    <directive-one />
    <directive-two />
</div>
```

I am using AngularJS v1.2.23.

http://plnkr.co/edit/3R3pfCTS0iK0IdHIdv84

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the problem was the self-closing directive tags i.e. .
Such tags are not supported by the HTML spec hence the HTML/browser parser ignores it. 
See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1237.

Got a couple answers, 
Answer 1: Use both open and close tags for the directives

```
<div>
    <directive-one></directive-one>
    <directive-two></directive-two>
</div>
```

Solution 2: Embed each directive within a div (somehow it works)

```
<div><directive-one /></div>
<div><directive-two /></div>
```

I am using AngularJS v1.2.23.

http://plnkr.co/edit/W6dFdxDESdTIQuCieqwz

Comment: One root element applies to html template of directive

Comment: I checked.. in my directives' template html, there is only one root element in each of them. But I still encountered this issue.

Comment: Can thou setup plunker with all directives showing the error

Comment: great... you found answer yourself :)